# REST ful Service different Content type for request and response

Tags: restful-architecture, messagebroker

As I have a requirement to build a rest service in Message broker to receive the multipart request from mobile apps and just passthrough the request to backoffice system to store the attachments in repository.

And back office system store the attachment and will send the http response to Message broker, then again message will passthrough the response back to mobile apps.

But the request message contentType= 'multipart/form-data' for attachment
and response message contentType= 'application/Json-data' for the status updates back to client system

So is it possible to have a different content type for request for 'multipart' and response 'json-data' for the rest http service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your REST service accepts and has a handler to process the multipart/form-data then it won't be a problem. Some services for example will ignore a request if it isn't in XML or JSON, others will accept various types of formats.

So check your REST service for what format it can process.

As for the response, again, if the client has a header stating it accepts JSON, then you can send it JSON. This is more easier to check as the REST service can check the "Accept" header on the request to determine if the client is happy to receive JSON.

Many REST services check this to send commonly either JSON or XML back.

So to summarise, yes you can mix and match request/response types as long as both the client and service are happy to accept and handle the request/response types.